# Linking to a page tab app on a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Is there a reliable way to link to an app on a Facebook page, when only the page ID and app ID are known? Specifically the URL to the page is not known, only the ID.

The documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/ claims that the following should work:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/PAGE_ID/app_YOUR_APP_ID
```

However when I try this, for example http://www.facebook.com/pages/null/126169047465269/app_222972467721305 does not work and instead I get "This content is currently unavailable".

Comment: Have you added the app tab to the page?

Comment: Where does that "null" come from? Lose it and see if it makes a difference. http://www.facebook.com/pages/126169047465269/app_222972467721305 (fails for me, but that might be the page not published, or you have changed the example?) Btu yes, it's possible.

Comment: Comes from the linked documentation by Facebook :) I did try it without, but doesn't work. I haven't changed anything, page 126169047465269 still has app 222972467721305 installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best form that will always work for a numeric page ID is this:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/PAGEID?sk=app_APPID

Replace PAGEID and APPID with numeric IDs.

If instead of a numeric page ID you have a username, then the URL should be of this form:

https://www.facebook.com/PAGEUSERNAME?sk=app_APPID
or
https://www.facebook.com/PAGEUSERNAME/app_APPID

Answer (score 0):

The Page here is not Public or maybe is not available?:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/126169047465269/

Try this,
 `https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME_OR_ID/app_222972467721305`

In the `PAGE_NAME_OR_ID` add `pages/126169047465269`,
if your page have a custom slug add the slug.

But to be sure check if your app is in a Sandbox mode or Unpublished.

Comment: Mostly right, except that the /pages/ URL is designed for SEO, so you're missing part of the path. Also, that form doesn't work, only the "sk=" query parameter method. It would actually be more like this: 

https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/126169047465269?sk_app_222972467721305

where "null" can actually be anything except blank.

Comment: I totally agree! But if you have activate the Custom Domain/Slug option you can't get back to the pages/126169047465269. You will get a Not Found page.